# spider = cls(*args, **kwargs) TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '_job'

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, scrapyd

Trying to use scrapyd for scraping using selenium and webdriver the spider is working fine with command "scrapy crawl myspider" but when i deploy using scrapyd and finally schedule it using curl and scrapyd api it trigger the unexpected keyword argument '_job'

Here is my spider code

```
#!G:\python-2-7
import scrapy
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.http import TextResponse
import time
from time import sleep
import pickle
import math
from math import floor
from thevillages.items import ThevillagesItem
import MySQLdb
import sys
import json

class VillageSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'village'
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com/']
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(VillageSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    # def __init__(self):
    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
```

Take a look a piece or error log below

```
2017-10-17 17:58:05 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:
2017-10-17 17:58:05 [twisted] CRITICAL: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:\python-2-7\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1386, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "g:\python-2-7\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 95, in crawl
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "g:\python-2-7\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 76, in crawl
    self.spider = self._create_spider(*args, **kwargs)
  File "g:\python-2-7\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 99, in _create_spider
    return self.spidercls.from_crawler(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "g:\python-2-7\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 54, in from_crawler
    spider = cls(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '_job'
```

Comment: using Scrapy 1.4.0 and scrapyd 1.2.0

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani thanks for the help. I got a fixed for that, issue was not with the code which i pasted in the question it is also working fine.The deployed project at scrapyd was caching or something i deleted the project using delproject.json scrapyd api then again deployed it then it started working fine. Also the answer you gave is working aswell. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need change your code to below

```
class VillageSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'village'
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com/']
    def __init__(self, name=None, **kwargs):
        kwargs.pop('_job')
        super(VillageSpider, self).__init__(name, **kwargs)
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    # def __init__(self):
    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
```

So that the definition of your init remains the same as the base class

Comment: Still getting the the same error in the scrapyd log

Comment: Please post scrapy and scrapyd version in your question